# How to use Qt library with VisualStudio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

At the official Qt library site present only Qt add-in for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. And there are no one for MSVS 2017.

How to use Qt library with visual studio 2017 in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [get the add-in beta here](https://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/), it should be mostly working. I mean if you want IDE integration. Otherwise it should build fine via the build tools command prompt (or however they call it now) via `qmake project` and then `make`.

As for building the Qt framework itself, it should probably work too, maybe with the exception of the `QWebEngine` stuff. It also seems that MSVC 2017 and 2015 are binary compatible, so it may be possible to use Qt binaries, built with MSVC 2015, therefore making it an option to avoid building Qt from source.

IIRC the incoming version 5.9 will offer MSVC 2017 prebuilt binaries.